# Android error cannot create "assets" folder because it already exists

Tags: android, android-assets

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-custom-fonts-in-your-android-apps.html) in order to use custom fonts in my android app:

The tutorial says to create an assets folder under the app folder but when  I try to do that I get the following error: "Error cannot create file, already exists"

However I looked through my project structure I do not see any assets folder:
[image: Project File Structure]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If any directory is empty, then Android Studio doesn't show the directory in `Android` mode. Change it to `Project` mode from dropdown.

[image]

Comment: Do you also know what type of directory the "fonts" folder should be in the assets folder?  Because I have the option of creating the fonts folder as a Directory or Android Resource Directory.

Comment: as directory would work. It should be inside "assets" btw.

Comment: I created a fonts directory inside of my assets folder and put a .otf font inside the directory. Since the directory now has something in it shouldn't it show in Android mode? Because my assets.font directory is not showing in Android mode.

Comment: It should show, just recheck using your computer's file browser if you have correctly configured everything. `fonts` directory should be inside `assets`. And you will put your fonts files inside `fonts`. Just verify the same using computer's file browser.

Comment: I found my assets folder inside my res folder is that where it should be?

Comment: No, `assets` should be inside `main` folder.